# How to stop MacBook Air 2023 from powering up with any key or touchpad press?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

CLARIFICATION: I'm looking for an answer to how to stop a powered down MacBook from turning on when ANY key is pressed.

Just as a note, the known procedure to (successfully) stop a powered down MacBook from turning on when we open its lid does not work to stop the powered down MacBook from turning on when ANY key is pressed. (some folks in the past suggested this as a solution to the question in this post)

Comment: Is this a question and what you’ve done thus far or is this a HOWTO?  It’s not clear what you’re trying to communicate here.

Comment: I've updated the post to be more clear. I'm asking for a solution to the question in the title.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448938/5472